# How to combine two queries?

Tags: mysql

I can't explain this very well except by spelling it out.

I start a query on `ID`, and from there I can get `TITLE, DATE, and REGNUMBER.`

The problem is I also want to get 'where,' which is also stored in `TITLE`. So I need to get `TITLE` from `REGNUMBER` this time, instead of from `ID`.

In the end I want

```
1) ID->TITLE | 2)DATE | 3)REGNUMBER | 4)WHERE(REGNUMBER->TITLE)
```

to be more clear, `TITLE` is on the same table in both cases. In the first case, I need to get `TITLE` from a join on `ID`, and in the second, from a `JOIN` on `REGNUMBER`.

```
id   -   title    -   date   -   regnumber   -   title(same field as col2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   -   event name   -   2/2/12   -   432   -   venue name
```

Comment: Show some sample data of the table. Otherwise, the question makes very little sense.

Comment: @user3637050 I have no idea what you're talking about. Your question is absolutely unclear.

Comment: I'm thinking of this in two parts. In the first, I search for events (TITLE) by registration date (DATE), and I select the REGNUMBER as well.
In the next part, I have to link to a different TITLE record (for venues), which I can get by joining REGNUMBER to the TITLE table on a different field.

Comment: So events get a TITLE, and venues get a TITLE. In the first part of the query, I'm joining on the events side of data, and in the second part, I need to escape that and join to the venue side, in order to get a different TITLE.

I can get columns 1-3 on the first set of joins, but I can only get column 4 from a different field on the column 3 field table.

Answer (score 0):

While there's still some missing info (it would help to know if there is only one table, or if there are two tables, the names of those tables, and which columns are held in each), I think this might help.

From what you wrote, it sounds like there are two tables (let's call them 'table1' and 'table2'), and table1 has columns 'id', 'title', 'date', while table2 has columns 'regnumber' and 'title'. Again, if I'm not understanding this, please correct me by providing more information about the tables and the structures of those tables.

It appears that you're missing information linking the 'id' of the event to the 'regnumber' of the venue. I think the best way of linking the event id to the venue regnumber is through a third table (we'll call it 'table3') with two foreign keys: 'event_id' (which would reference the 'id' column in table1) and 'venue_id' (which would reference the 'regnumber' in table2).

Before I move on to the SQL, let's make sure the structure of our three tables looks like the following:

> table1: id, title, date
>
> table2: regnumber, venue
>
> table3: event_id, venue_id

With each event 'id' paired with a 'venue_id' in table3, we can move on to writing the following query.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, t1.date, t2.regnumber, t2.venue FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3 WHERE t1.id = t3.event_id;
```

The reason you'll want a third table is because multiple events will happen in the same venue, and events can happen across multiple venues (like the concert series SXSW).